# Delete all pointers that point to a certain value

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm not 100% sure on how to phrase this properly, but let's say I have two pointers, a and b that both point to c.  Knowing only c, how do I delete all pointers that point to that?  If I know a and b, I can use delete, but suppose I don't.

Edit: I'm trying to implement pop in a linked list, by navigating to the last element, and then deleting that.  But how do I free up the pointer of the second last element?

Comment: Please include the problem you are really trying to solve.

Comment: Use [`shared_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/)

Comment: you can't do that. What problem are you trying to solve? What you're doing sounds similar to what `shared_ptr` does, but without knowing what problem you are trying to solve, it's impossible to say. All we can say is that the solution you're pursuing will not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "delete all the pointers that point to c"?

Comment: You don't delete a pointer, you delete the thing the pointer points too. I suppose you want to delete that object and reset all the pointers that used to reference it to null?

Comment: I updated the question, I'm messing around with linked lists.

Comment: `But how do I free up the pointer of the second last element?`: You just don't free them, since the adress that were pointing to is already freed.

Comment: Wouldn't that give undefined behaviour though, because the object the pointer is pointing to is removed?

Comment: @CSGregorian not as long as you don't dereference the pointer afterwards.

Comment: @CSGregorian Don't you want to then point that pointer to the next item in the list? if you have a list of `a-->b-->c` and you pop `b`, wouldn't you want `a-->c`?

Comment: Take note that with a pointer to the second last element, you can delete the next one *and* set the second last's pointer to null very easily.

Comment: @Josh I'm just popping the last element for now, but I'll try that after.

Comment: @chris It seems like that would be easiest, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question makes no sense.

When you have 2 pointers to the same object :

```
p1 ---------
           |
           |----> Object
p2 ---------
```

If you call `delete` on ***either*** p1 or p2, the object destructor is called and the memory occupied is freed. No need to call `delete` on all pointers.

If you are looking for shared ownership of your object, go for [`std::shared_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're thinking?

```
struct node {
    int payload;
    node *nxt;
}

class List {
    private:
        node *head;
        node *tail;

    public:
        ...

        void pop_back() {
            node *holder;
            //Set holder to the second to last item
            for(holder = head; holder->nxt->nxt; holder = holder->nxt) ;
            delete holder->nxt; //Delete the last item (could also be delete tail)
            holder->nxt = 0;    //Set holder's next pointer to null
            tail = holder;      //Set tail to holder
        }
};
```

Comment: Ultimately this is what I want to do, yeah.  I didn't think of keeping a pointer to the tail as well!

Comment: @CSGregorian It's not necessary, but it makes `push_back`'s easier. Notice how I only ever used tail to update it in this funct. There is such a thing as a double sided list, who's nodes point both forward and backwards. Though they're more trouble to maintain, they make this kind of operation easier.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just *keep* the pointer to the second-last element. What you describe is the behaviour of a GC, and you don't write a GC to delete a node in a linked list.

Also, as comments point out : you *delete* an object pointed to by a pointer, but you don't delete the pointer ; you *reset* it (to nullptr in your case).